# What is the best size (dimensions) for product photos for front page and category pages?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

I have installed the Porto theme in my Magento 1.9.1 store. I have 8 rows of products on the front page (4 products per row). Now the front page as well as all the category pages don't look very attractive because the photos of products look different sizes (dimensions). I assume there is a re-sizing mechanism within Magento and it takes the large base image and shrinks it to a specific size to be displayed on the front page (and category pages). I think the problem might be that some of my base images are not big enough (or don't have the correct ratio) to begin with. How to best correct this?

I noticed that within the Admin - there are 3 options in the Image tab:

- Base Image
- Small Image
- Thumbnail

I guess I can make a specific size of my products' photos and save them as Small Images? in the Image tab of "Manage products". What would be the ideal size (dimensions) and where is this specified within Admin? I mean something like 300 x 400 or 300 x 500? Where is this specified and what do you recommend? Another benefit of re-sizing the images manually would be that I could decrease the actual file size for the front page (and category) images and increase the speed of the site.

I have the following settings in

> SYSTEM --) CONFIGURATION --) CATALOG --) Catalog - Product Image:

```
Base Image Width = 1800
Small Image Width = 210
```

I tried changing the Small Image Width to *410* but I didn't notice any difference anywhere...

Here is an image guide for Magento 1.9.x:

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-image-size-type.html

*It says under Small Image:*

**Example size:
470 x 470 pixels**

### Are these the right dimensions? Where is it specified?

I found this piece of code in the list.phtml file in:

> /public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_image_helper = $this->helper('catalog/image');
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $code  = $store->getCode();
    $aspect_ratio = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/aspect_ratio",$code);
    $ratio_width = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/ratio_width",$code);
    $ratio_height = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/ratio_height",$code);

    if(!$ratio_width)
        $ratio_width = 300;
    if(!$ratio_height)
        $ratio_height = 400;
?>
<?php
```

**Does that mean my front page images and images in categories are being re-sized to 300 x 400 pixels?**